# The true dimension of Dirac field

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dimensional-analysis, dirac-equation, spinors

In natural units with $\hbar=1$ and $c=1$, as we know, the energy
dimension of the Dirac field $\psi(x)$ in QED is $\frac{3}{2}$.
But in cgs units, what is the true dimension of the Dirac field $\psi(x)$
in terms of cm, g and s? It seems that only the energy dimension of
the Dirac field $\psi(x)$ is physical, is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Lagrangian for Dirac's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac_Lagrangian) is
$$
\mathcal L=-mc^2\psi^2+\cdots \tag{1}
$$

As we know that $H\sim\mathrm d^3\boldsymbol x\ \mathcal L$ has units of energy, we conclude that
$$
\psi^2\sim x^{-3}\tag{2}
$$
and therefore $\psi$ has units of $[\mathrm{length}]^{-3/2}$. If you use a different convention for $\mathcal L$ instead of $(1)$ you'll get a different result.

Comment: So if we use different conventions as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} & = & -mc^{2}\psi+\cdots\\
\mathcal{L} & = & -m\psi+\cdots\\
\mathcal{L} & = & -mc^{2}\hbar^{3}\psi+\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}


then $\psi$ may have different dimensions (up to some orders of $\hbar$
and $c$). These different dimensions of $\psi$ may not influence
physical observables. Is this right?

Comment: @RenhongFang yes, exactly :-)

Comment: @RenhongFang anyway, if you think that my post was useful and fully answers to your question, it would be nice for you to click on the accept button (tick mark) so that the question gets the "answered" status.

Comment: I am just a fresh, and thanks you for reminding me of this :-)